# R: Dplyr Lagging Variables after Grouping by Multiple Columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to calculate the `score` difference after grouping by `Year, State, Tier, Group`. A stylised representation of my data would look like:

```
dat2 <- data.frame(
Year = sample(1990:1996, 10, replace = TRUE),
State = sample(c("AL", "CA", "NY"), 10, replace = TRUE),
Tier = sample(1:2),
Group = sample(c("A", "B"), 10, replace = TRUE),
Score = rnorm(10))
```

I tried `mutate` with `group_by_` and `.dots` however it obtains values from the next absolute value (i.e. grouping does not seem to work). I am mostly interested in plotting the yearly differences (ala time-series even though some years would be `NA`) so this can be solved by either lagging or calculating the next year's score.

**Edit:** So, if the dataset looks like:

```
Year    State    Tier    Group    Score
1990    AL       1       A        75
1990    AL       2       A        100
1990    AL       1       B        5
1990    AL       2       B        10
1991    AL       1       A        95
1991    AL       2       A        80
1991    AL       1       B        5
1991    AL       2       B        15
```

The desired end result would be:

```
Year    State    Tier    Group    Score   Diff
1991    AL       1       A        95      20     
1991    AL       1       B        5       0  
1991    AL       2       A        80      -20
1991    AL       2       B        15      5
```

Comment: Can you show what is the desired result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to calculate the difference in `Score` within each combination of `Year, State, Tier, Group`? Presumably, your data will be sorted chronologically for the difference to make any sense. Your example is small for these combinations to be repeated but I believe the solution you are looking for would be:

```
library(dplyr)
dat2 %>% 
 arrange(Year) %>%
 group_by(State, Tier, Group) %>%
 mutate(ScoreDiff = Score - lag(Score))
```

With your current code, the `ScoreDiff` column has a lot of `NAs` because there usually won't be multiple cases of the same combination of your four variables in just 10 cases. But you can try it with a more general code (I've also changed the starting year to 1890 from 1990):

```
n <- 100

dat2 <- data.frame(
  Year = sample(1890:1996, n, replace = TRUE),
  State = sample(c("AL", "CA", "NY"), n, replace = TRUE),
  Tier = sample(1:2),
  Group = sample(c("A", "B"), n, replace = TRUE),
  Score = rnorm(n))

dat2 %>%
  arrange(Year) %>%
  group_by(State, Tier, Group) %>%
  mutate(ScoreDiff = Score - lag(Score))
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the post. This is roughly what I thought would do the trick by it does not work for me. When I run your longer sample, it only calculates the difference if the same Year/State/Tier/Group combination has two entries - so it does not lag the score but only operates with duplicates.

Comment: You are right. Because `Year` was included in the grouping, it would look for the same combinations including the same `Year`. I've edited the answer accordingly, and the code above should now produce your desired outcome.